# Microsoft Graph API using filter on get sharepoint lists

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to filter on the sharepoint lists, but the semantics seems to be different to the [default semantics](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter).

What I already tried was (with $ and without; single quotes and no quotes):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?filter=name eq 'Something'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?$filter=name eq 'Something'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?filter=id eq 'CFFF1460-B4D7-419C-A921-61B5279BBDDC'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?$filter=id eq 'CFFF1460-B4D7-419C-A921-61B5279BBDDC'
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?filter=id eq CFFF1460-B4D7-419C-A921-61B5279BBDDC
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?$filter=id eq CFFF1460-B4D7-419C-A921-61B5279BBDDC
```

But everything returns an array containing all lists and not only the subset matching the desired criteria.

So how can I filter on sharepoint lists?

Comment: I'm afraid the list collection cannot be filtered or searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately (like Marc already mentioned in the comments) it is not possible to filter on SharePoint lists. If you need to, you have to do it on the client side, by reading the list without any filter and make a LINQ statement (or something similar) on the received collection. Be aware that (like all collections in Graph) you don't get always all elements at once. Potentially you have to call the next link request from the last response and wade through more requests and elements till you find what you need.

So when you found what you need, it is a good idea to store the list id within a memory cache or Redis cache for faster lookups the next time, you need this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id of the list you want to filter and get a response for.

YOu can run a graph API query like this.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/{list-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/%7Blist-id%7D)

This will give you data about that list.

Let me know if you need further details on this.

Comment: If you know the id, then everything is simple. But if you only have a name, then this approach doesn't work. In that case I'm currently fetch all lists, make the filtering on client side and hold a dictionary in cache name -> list of matching ids. Nevertheless this is problematic if lists are going to change. Fortunately this is very rare in our case and it works to regulary refresh the cache. But it would be much easier if sharepoint lists could be filtered.

Comment: Okay, got it. In that case that will work for you. If you think the answer is appropriate for other users, please upvote or accept for the better reach of other users.